# How to share a post using Selenium on Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I managed to reach a group's page; now I want to locate the share button of their last post, and click on it.

I have failed to find anything making it identifiable (div class, etc.) All I get is an a class and don't know what to do with it.

This did not work:

```
share=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('Share')
share.click()
```

Comment: from chrome, inspect element , hover on button and try to copy that xpath.    try element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop-header-cnt']/div[2]/div[3]/input")

Comment: xpath would be easy to copy.

Comment: is the button on the screen, or you have to scroll down?

Comment: Thanks. I have to scroll down!

Comment: Your line of code gave this: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //*[@id='desktop-header-cnt']/div[2]/div[3]/input

and the xpath looks like this: /html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[3]/a which is ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

Try this process by that Share button's `CSS` selector

To get specific element `CSS` selector

1. Inspect the share button
2. Then right-click on that share button `HTML` element
3. Go TO `Copy` > `Copy selector`

.

```
share=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("paste_css_selector_here") 
share.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the css selector it's giving me: #u_0_81 > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)
It's not working: NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #u_0_81 > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)

Comment: @Tommygarçon Actually `#u_0_81` is randomly generated id that's why we can't hardcode it in our `code`.

Comment: Now what you have to do is find a parent class of `> div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)` this element's outer div.

Comment: ook if the element which contains this `#u_0_81` randomly generated id also have some static class. And try to put that class in place of this id.